# Send Access Token by axios with a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I don't understand the variable token doesn't set data that is taken from the local storage

Error that i get is

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
[0]     at JSON.parse ()**

```
const tokenizedCartRedirect = (history) => {
    var token  = localStorage.getItem("currentToken");

    if (token) {
      const config = {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "x-auth-token": token },
        mode: "cors",
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify("sample data");
      const res = axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/auth", body, config)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("it is pushed");
          history.push("/cart");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          history.push("/login");
        });
    } else {
      history.push("/login");
    }
  };
```

Comment: I tested the code, the token is gained from the local repository, but still

Comment: Where are you parsing this `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Where is the error that you're seeing, in the `catch`? And also, `sample data` is not a valid `JSON` in the `body` of your `POST` request, so perhaps what you need is something along the lines of `JSON.stringify({ payload: "sample data" });`

Comment: nope, still didn't work

Comment: Same error or something else? What if you just pass the object `{ payload: "sample data" }` itself without doing `JSON.stringify()`, and is the `/auth` route supposed to return a `JSON` payload? Can you confirm that's in fact the case?

Comment: yes, this worked before when i treid from postman and it works perfectly when the token and the content type is placed inside the header,  but after adding , "x-auth-token": token it doesnt

Comment: So the same exact request with token works in `Postman` but doesn't work with `axios`? Does the `x-auth-token` need the type in front of it? For example, `Bearer {token}`? What if you get rid of `mode: cors`? Is `CORS` enabled on the server? Perhaps that's the issue - `CORS` wouldn't apply to `Postman` but will be important in the browser.

Comment: i have installed the npm cors and intiated the middleware for all requests using app.use(cors()); but its not working.

Comment: How does the request looks like in the `network` tab in your browser? Are there any other warnings, errors, in the `console`?

Comment: Im so sorry it worked I hve been sending a post to a get method